# Why is physical distance not modelled on rational numbers?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

Physicists use real numbers to model distance or physical line. My intuition is completely neutral on whether to use rational numbers or reals for physical quantities like distance, or temperature etc. Is there any historical or psychological reasons do prefer reals? Or there is some mathematical advantages working with real. Is calculus on rational numbers harder than calculus on reals?

Comment: You have a unit square with coordinates $A(0,0)$, $B(1,0)$, $C(1,1)$, $D(1,0)$. What is the length $AC$? Is the value rational?

Comment: @WillR You don't have a unit square in the real world. Or you can put forward a kind of geometry that you cannot draw a straight line from any point to any point.

Comment: Why not? If you have rational distances in the real world, then what is stopping us from constructing a unit square? You could argue that we should also consider rational angles, but then I can come up with a measuring system different from that of "angle" where the equivalent of a right-angle is given by a rational value. See, for example, the notion of "[spread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Spread_compared_to_angle)" compared to angle.

Comment: why not? because mathematical objects live in our minds. you cannot point out and show me a perfect square outside!

Comment: I apologise, I think I misunderstood your first response. I thought you were trying to say that the "nonexistence" of unit squares means that the irrational length is irrelevant. However, it appears now that you are arguing more strongly: you're saying that because unit squares "don't exist" (in a sense), my question is irrelevant regardless of the irrational lengths. Correct?
But in that case, why do we bother with any model of geometry? We want to have some model; my original point was that if you want to measure such distances within your model, the rationals don't seem to cut it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calculus over the rational numbers is really not so pleasant. For example, the Intermediate Value Theorem, The Maximum Value Theorem, and The Mean Value Theorem all fail for functions continuous on the rationals.

Edit: A better alternative for $\mathbb{Q}$ would be the completion of it with respect to a $p$-adic metric (or the real numbers, of course). Calculus over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has been studied, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_analysis). See also for $p$-adic quantum mechanics.

Comment: The physical world as we know it can be described very efficiently by mathematics based open the real (and complex) numbers. At a Planck scale a $p$-adic topology may become more relevant.

Comment: @gtgyn: the function $x \mapsto x^2$ cannot satisfy the intermediate value property when restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$. If you need the intermediate value property and you reject irrational numbers, you are restricted to affine functions ($ x \mapsto a + b x$) and any discontinuous oddities that happen to map intervals to intervals  (in $\mathbb{Q}$).

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically formal considerations of measuring starts with Greeks, as far as I know. Let us first consider Euclidean geometry, where we can *construct* right triangle with leg lengths $1$ and $1$. What is the length of hypotenuse? It is (the positive) solution of equation $x^2 = 2$ by Pythagoras theorem, easily shown not to be rational number. Furthermore, $\pi$ is *by definition* such number that circumference of a circle is given by $C = 2r\pi$, also not rational. Skipping some time ahead, yet another important mathematical constant is given as limit of sequence of rational numbers: $e = \lim_n(1+\frac 1n)^n$ which is not rational. Point being, reals emerge naturally even while we do elementary constructions.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the rationals *are* used for all experimental measurements. But as others are trying to tell you, it makes a lot of sense to do theoretical work and formula development in the *idealized* world of reals, and then map back to rational approximations when actual measurements and calculations are needed. There really is no harm in doing this given that the reals and rationals are dense in each other. And while there are not perfect squares or circles, it really is not better to use rational approximations of these objects. The *completeness* of the reals is used all over the place in calculus, and the rationals simply are not complete. Do theory in the reals and map back to rationals when you need a measurement.

Answer (score -2):

The very definition of "physical quantities" is that they are "measurable".  Irrational numbers cannot, by definition, be measurable.  So either our definition of physical quantities is wrong, or incomplete, or all operations on physical quantities must be represented by operations only on rational numbers which must reduce to operations on the reals in the limit of idealistic models of relationships between physical quantities, such as the use of calculus of variations to solve Lagrangians and Hamiltonians.

Comment: `Irrational numbers cannot, by definition, be measurable` This makes no sense at all. The numerical value of a physical measurement depends on the unit of measure. For example, the measure of a physical angle can be a rational when measured in degrees vs. an irrational when measured in radians (or viceversa). Both numbers are equally legitimate physical measurements.

Comment: If you represent an angle as pi/4 and say that it is equivalent to 90 degrees you are dealing with idealized representations of a physical quantity (the angle.)  You will never find a real world example of a 90 degree angle because if you are a good scientist, you will always include your uncertainty in that measurement.  That uncertainty is not due to sloppy measuring--it is inherent to any real world measurement.

Comment: `You will never find a real world example of a 90 degree angle` This directly contradicts what you wrote in the question about `in the limit of idealistic models`. If you now mean to say that the result of a measurement is *not* an exact number, then it makes even less sense to wonder whether that whatever-else-it-may-be is rational or not.

Comment: Something like a length interval is measured in terms of a rational value followed by a rational valued uncertainty that indicate various levels of confidence.